# Rewriting to IsolatedStorage

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

Hi trying to write data to isolated storage to save state of an app. The user has the option to save data when needed so I want to be able to over write any previously saved data. The number oof data items is constant each time it's saved.

Code so far:

```
 IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
 public static void savePlayerState()
 {
     settings.Add("currentSeriesNumber", PlayerState.CurrentSeriesNo.ToString());
     etc
 }

 public static void loadPlayerState()
 {
     PlayerState.CurrentSeriesNo = (int.Parse(settings["currentSeriesNumber"].ToString()));
     etc
 }
```

But this only allows me to write data once any further save attempts and not stored? I tried to remove the entries before storing any new data but this didn't work and can't find info for the method I'm using except a brief tutorial.

Help here appreciated?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You just use the indexer to set, which means effectively "add or replace":

```
settings["currentSeriesNumber"]  = PlayerState.CurrentSeriesNo.ToString();
```

Comment: great so create the entries (setings.Add) in a constructor and then use settings["blah"] when needed?

Comment: @TripVoltage right, if you just want to add or replace (if the key already exists), then use settings["blah"].

Comment: +1, @TripVoltage - don't forget to call settings.Save() when you finish changes - it doesn't save automatically.